# BSOD Error code 0xc0000185 when connected to internet via wifi dongle

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ssd, bsod

I have a problem where my PC restarts every 5 minutes with Blue Screen of Death. I couldn't access `.dmp` files but managed to take a photo since it happens quite often.

From what I have managed to find on he internet [it seems like SSD](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2009370/system-restore-windows-boot-past-bsod-error-code-0xc0000185.html) issue so I am scanning the disk and it does have a lot of files without parent and unindexed ones, no bad sectors so far.
What puzzles me is that I have been scanning disk for more than an hour or so without BSOD and I would get it only when dongle is plugged in.

I have tried downloading [Dump file reader](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315263#method1) but it's online install and system always crashes before download finishes.

**EDIT:** Following advice from @MRK. I have `ntoskrnl.exe  ntoskrnl.exe+6965c  fffff800'03402000   fffff800'039ee000   0x005ec000  0x556356e8  25/05/2015 18:07:52 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NT Kernel & System  6.1.7601.18869 (win7sp1_gdr.150525-0603)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe`   in all dump files at the top.

[Some articles claim that it's RAM failing](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2209014/bsod-ntoskrnl-exe-windows.html) I am [running memory test ATM](http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/test-your-ram-with-windows-memory-diagnostic-tool/).

**UPDATE:** Finished test - It's not RAM.

[Link to Dump File sample](http://www.filedropper.com/061915-29078-01)

**UPDATE 2** Since Wifi dongle had warranty, I returned it back and got new one, BSOD still happens so we can eliminate wifi dongle.

Values [from disk utility](http://osdn.jp/projects/crystaldiskinfo/downloads/63423/CrystalDiskInfo6_5_2-en.exe/) look like this:

[image]

and

[image]

**UPDATE 3** It does detect drive in [OCZ Toolbox](http://ocz.com/consumer/download/firmware/OCZToolbox_v4.9.0.634_win32.zip)

[image]

**How could I debug it any further?**

Comment: You need to debug this further.  If you suspect the dongle elminate it has a possible cause of this problem.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could explain why the down votes?

Comment: Have you got up to date anti-virus & firewall installed and running?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I do, AVG 2015. Have done full PC scan yesterday.

Comment: share the dmp file. BlueScreenView  is crap and only gives useless data.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Done added 'Link to Dump File sample', I really appreciate you trying to help. Thanks.

Comment: the dmp shows that you have this crash: CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION (f4): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Test the Smart values of the SSD with this tool: http://osdn.jp/projects/crystaldiskinfo/releases/63423. Are they ok? Do you use the latest firmware? The crucial M4 casued such a rash after using the SSD for 5000hrs which was fixed in a newer firmware.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have updated the question, we can eliminate the wifi dongle, did screenshots for the CrystalDiskInfo. I am not sure what those values mean. :) Thanks.

Comment: is this the latest firmware version? OCZ SSDs are known to be buggy as hell and cause a lot of BSODs.

Comment: @magicandre1981 it's not. Did everything in instructions from OCZ (have set drive as IDE, burned CD from ISO, and made Blue-ray boot device) When I got app running in DOS it still wouldn't not see SSD drive only HDD Toshiba. Couldn't update it firmware - opened case with OCZ will see what they say.

Comment: Inside Windows, can you run the OCZ Toolbox and does it detect the drive there?

Comment: can you do a firmware update inside the OCZ toolbox?

Comment: @magicandre1981 It allows to download image, i am away till Thursday will test it then. Thanks Andre.

Comment: have you tested the new firmware? Is the issue gone?

Comment: @magicandre1981 sent SSD to OCZ should arrive back sometime next week.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i think it is safe to assume it was SSD. After it arrived refurbished no more issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `0xc0000185` means `STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR` which is a IO error:

> The I/O device reported an I/O error.

This has nothing to with a WIFI dongle, but can be caused by old SSD firmwares or damaged SSD drives.

RMA the SSD and get a new drive.

Answer (score 1):

BSOD Not only happen due to bad hardware also (and mostly in my case) happen due to Hardware Drivers/Windows Services! So maybe your problem is only your WiFi driver that cause this problem or ..!?

To find out, you can try free [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) program from NirSoft. It is small utility that try read *.dmp file and show you last active files before BSOD happen. usually one or more files from 4~6 top files in the list cause the problem. (those are identity in read raw's)

By looking into that list you can find Driver/Software names that can cause your problem.

Just in case, If your Windows do not create any dump files in BSOD!? you can read this help: [Dump Files - Configure Windows to Create on BSOD](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/174459-dump-files-configure-windows-create-bsod.html)

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius, Your welcome. Well you need put at least 4 or 6 names of top files like you did for first one. As i mention in my last post, it could be one or more of those 4~6 top files but not necessary the #1 ! do you see any name that indicate to your wifi driver!? or any other hardware drives!?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius, I don't think it is your memory! as you mention in your post title, you have this problem when you use your WiFi dongle! so if you do not have this problem when you playing a game or do some stuff in graphic applications like Photoshop, I guess your computer RAM is fine! anyway you can use this app too: http://www.memtest86.com/ use its free edition. We use it a lot to check memories!

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius, I didn't see your new updates! (We only get notifications on new posts and not updates!)
About WiFi: as I mentioned, often BSOD happen due to drivers. So I am suggesting that you uninstall your WiFi driver and use older or newer version from its manufacture support page. If problem exist or there was not any other driver in manufacture support page, you can uninstall your current WiFi driver and then go to Windows Update. most of the time Microsoft have a driver for our devices that work without any problem on windows.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius:
About Dump File: I checked it. I found this file "lltdio.sys" cause you BSOD. I am not familiar with that file so I Google it and I found this Topic:
http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f299/solved-windows-7-ultimate-bsod-when-on-wifi-intel-4965agn-429459.html
 It seems that user also have problem with WiFi and by changing it to different brand and model his problem solved! I still suggest to change driver if problem did not solved, I suggest test another wifi dungle!

Comment: @MRK as I said, BlueScreenView is crap. The driver is NOT the cause. Use Windbg to see more details. lltdio.sys is a driver from Windows (Link-Layer Topology Mapper I/O Driver).

Comment: @MRK I have replaced dongle, with different (brand) one and still getting BSOD which makes it very unlikely that it's wifi dongle.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the dongle has created some system errors on your computer. Even if you have removed the dongle, the damage has been done, hence the error. You need to try to undo the damage to fix this. Have you tried Automated Repair or [System Restore](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-system-restore-a5ae3ed9-07c4-fd56-45ee-096777ecd14e) to fix this [0x0000185 BSOD](https://softwaretested.com/windows/blue-screen-recovery-error-0x0000185/)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).